# Streaming resultset in derby

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

i'm just trying to work with derby.I got a doubt does derby have a Streaming resultSet option like jdbc if yes will it do automatically or any configurations are required.

I will have 10 million records that have to export as a sql dump using java.
If i access using `select * from table` will i get a heap space exception?
Each row size is not more than 2000 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby will stream the results by default (automatically).  See [this thread](http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/Streaming-Results-td104818.html).